# How to confirm a library is linked statically?

Tags: linux, cmake, makefile, linker, libcurl

I've edited my CMake script to link libcurl with my C++ application on Linux.

Besides adding libcurl to my target link libraries, I've set the libcurl flag `DCURL_STATICLIB`.

What is the definitive way of checking this has linked statically, rather than dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the definitive way of checking this has linked statically, rather than dynamically?

Run the `ldd` program on the generated executable(s).  This will give you a list of all the shared libraries that are dynamically linked to it.  Verify that `libcurl.so` is not on the list.

```
ldd my_executable
```

It may be useful to engage `grep` to filter out other shared libs:

```
ldd my_executable | grep libcurl
```

, but because that will produce no output when `libcurl` indeed is not dynamically linked to the executable, the unfiltered form is useful at least for confirming that `ldd` actually worked.